# Restricted bash | Unable to execute remote command

Tags: linux, bash

I setup restricted bash for a user (scriptsser) on Machine A and created symlinks to the desired commands as below

```
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10 Nov 28 08:09 touch -> /bin/touch
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  8 Nov 28 08:09 ssh -> /bin/ssh
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  7 Dec 18 07:44 mv -> /bin/mv
```

Everything works fine and I am able to use these commands while I am logged in to Machine A with this user (scriptsser)

My problem starts when I try to execute a command from a remote machine; say Machine B.

```
ssh scriptsser@MachineA -i /home/scriptsser/.ssh/id_rsa  "mv /file1 /file2" ;
```

I get the following error message.

> rbash: /bin/rbash: restricted: cannot specify `/' in command names

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's right in the man page: specifying command names containing /, or specifying a filename containing a / as an argument to the .  builtin command are both forbidden.

Comment: right - but where did I specify a command with a leading slash @ajgringo619 ? In my remote command I only pointed to "mv" and not "/bin/mv", right?

Comment: Ahh, but you are: mv = /bin/mv (per your symlink).

Comment: Okay - I even tried copying the actual command /bin/mv to the user's home path and still getting the same result.

Comment: I think the error has nothing to do with `mv /file1 /file2`. For some reason `rbash` is trying to run `/bin/rbash`. If it tried to run `/bin/echo` then the error would start with `rbash: /bin/echo:`. Compare `rbash -c '/bin/echo'` and `rbash -c '/bin/rbash'`.

Comment: You're right @KamilMaciorowski I just realized that I had to add "/bin/rbash" in the authorized_keys options section to force the user in the rbash once is logged in. 

But if I removed it, how am I going to force the user in the rbash when logged ( ssh ) in

Comment: I don't know. Consider [edit]ing/rebuilding the question and including your discovery in the question body.

Comment: Are you using SSH `ForceCommand`?

Comment: @muru Yes, I was using it.. Now I removed it. But that makes the user able to execute any command ( not just that ones I assigned to it )

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had '/bin/rbash' set in authorized_keys for the user "scriptsser".

Comment: It’s not clear to me that this answers the question.  If it does, please explain how.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.) Perhaps this should be an edit to the question?